# 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because it could not be found

Tags: visual-studio

I have several database references in a database project and I have had to add additional databases because I was getting the same error (but with the name of each database projects), but there is nothing at all inside my solution called `master.decpac`.

The error is:

> The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.

What is `master.dacpac` and what could I do to resolve the error I'm having?

Thanks

**EDIT** I have narrowed it down to just one database project. Deleting the database reference to the project will remove the error. While it isn't a viable solution, at least we know it is only one project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.

`master` is a system database.

To add it as a reference to your database project you select References > Add Database Reference and then select the System database radio button. In the drop down available, select Master and then select ok.

The system database was referenced in the project and was also needed inside of the new database project.